# Mount S3 File System in AWS Lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, filesystems, aws-lambda

Do you know if it possible mounting a File System over AWS S3 to increase AWS Lambda storage?

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions only

Answer (score 14):

You **cannot** mount Amazon S3 as a filesystem for use with AWS Lambda.

AWS Lambda functions are designed to be **short-running scripts** that respond to an event in your environment (eg data coming into a Kinesis stream, a file being created in Amazon S3). They typically run only for a few seconds.

While you haven't described your use-case, something that requires heavy use of a filesystem is not a typically good use of a Lambda function.

You can, of course, **retrieve and create objects in Amazon S3 via SDK calls from the Lambda function**. This is a very fast and efficient way to load/store data from Lambda.

Comment: You can. Several examples in the official AWS docs do just this, e.g. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pinpoint/latest/developerguide/tutorials-importing-data-lambda-function-input-split.html

Comment: Interesting. That code sample uses `s3fs` to 'mount' S3. I normally see recommendations not to use `s3fs` because it can be less reliable than directly calling the S3 API. Amazing that they've put an `s3fs` example in the documentation!

Answer (score 8):

The storage space provided with lambda is actually **Ephemeral disk space** that can be used for temporary storage during lambda execution only. It is limited to **512 Mb** and can't be increased.

If your use-case needs more space for lambda  than you can store and retrieve objects directly from s3 . It's highly fast and efficient. Moreover , s3 doesn't provide a file system , it is only object based storage and every folder , subfolder, and every file represents an **object** in s3 which virtually seems like a hierarchical structure but in actual it's not.

While the temporary disk space in lambda has a hierarchical file structure

Comment: It should be noted that although the disk space is ephemeral, it is retained between invocations on the same container instance. Therefore if you're storing files in `/tmp` that it can fill up and cause all subsequent functions to fail until AWS spins up a new instance.

Answer (score 4):

After recent feature updates to AWS, you can now mount EFS into your Lambda filesystem:
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-amazon-efs-for-aws-lambda-in-your-serverless-applications/

Comment: I got this working a couple years ago, but it wasn't intuitive and I felt exposed in terms of security. Probably better off using S3.

Answer (score 2):

To address the comments in https://stackoverflow.com/a/50982764/1259398:

It seems you are confusing the Python library s3fs which emulates a file system, but is a library on top of Boto, with the s3fs-fuse module which 'mounts' an S3 bucket under a specified folder and this becomes accessible to the entire OS as if was a regular hierarchical FS.

References:

- s3fs-fuse - https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse
- s3fs Python module - https://github.com/dask/s3fs & https://fs-s3fs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/
- How to use - https://medium.com/swlh/using-s3-just-like-a-local-file-system-in-python-497737783f11

Answer (score 1):

A more recent update from AWS now allows an increase in the AWS Lambda /tmp directory up to 10GB, [AWS Lambda Now Supports Up to 10 GB Ephemeral Storage](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/aws-lambda-now-supports-up-to-10-gb-ephemeral-storage/), but that is ephemeral for processing larger workloads, etc. The article has a table breakdown of the latest storage (ephemeral and non-ephemeral) options available as well.

[image: AWS Lambda Storage Options]