# AWS Lambda and S3: passing s3 object path to image process function

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

My intention is to have a large image stored on my S3 server and then get a lambda function to read/process the file and save the resulting output(s). I'm using a package called [python-bioformats](https://pypi.org/project/python-bioformats/) to work with a proprietary image file (which is basically a whole bunch of tiffs stacked together). When I use

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):

    import boto3

    key = event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key'].encode("utf-8")
    bucket = 'bucketname'

    s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
    imageobj = s3.Object(bucket, key).get()['Body'].read()

    bioformats.get_omexml_metadata(imageobj)
```

I have a feeling that the lambda function tries to download the entire file (5GB) when making imageobj. Is there a way I can just get the second function (which takes a filepath as argument) to refer to the s3 object in a filepath-like manner? I'd also like to not expose the s3 bucket/object publicly, so doing this server-side would be ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `bioformats.get_omexml_metadata()` function requires a filepath as an argument, then you will need to have the object downloaded before calling the function.

This could be a problem in an AWS Lambda function because there is a 500MB limit on available disk space (and only in `/tmp/`).

If the data can instead be processed as a stream, you could read the data as it is required without saving to disk first. However, the [`python-bioformats` documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/python-bioformats/) does not show this as an option. In fact, I would be surprised if your above code works, given that it is expecting a **path** while `imageobj` is the *contents* of the file.

Comment: That's my thinking too. I initially assumed that lambda could read s3 objects like a regular filepath. Then I though maybe a stream could work - but as you said, bioformats requires a path. I have a feeling I'm fresh out of luck and have to process the file prior to upload.

Comment: Also considered mounting the s3 to the lambda using s3fs, but that's not advisable: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50982548/mount-s3-file-system-in-aws-lambda

Comment: Boto streaming bodies will most likely not be able to dish out the slices of data I need, as the file is delimited in an opaque way: https://botocore.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/response.html#botocore.response.StreamingBody.iter_lines

Comment: Yeah, can't think of another way :/

Comment: Amazon EC2 instances are very low-cost (~1c/hour for a t3.micro), so feel free to use it instead of Lambda (or have Lambda launch an EC2 instance).

Comment: I think I'll do exactly that. Ty for the help!