# Is it possible to install s3fs-fuse inside a aws lambda function?

Tags: python, aws-lambda, ffmpeg, filesystems, s3fs

I want to extract images via `ffmpeg` to `s3 bucket` but not sure actually how to do this as `s3` is different from `local filesystem`.

So after searching a bit i found `s3fs-fuse` but not sure how i can install and use it inside lambda function.

Can anyone please explain, how can i do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mount S3 File System in AWS Lambda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50982548/mount-s3-file-system-in-aws-lambda)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `boto3`, which is the AWS SDK for Python.

See: [S3 — Boto3 Docs documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html)

It has functions for uploading and downloading files to S3.

Note that in AWS Lambda functions, you can only store files in the `/tmp/` directory, and there is a default limit of 512MB of storage space, but you can request it up to 10GB (for an extra cost).

Comment: Small correction: a _minimum_ of 512MB storage space, maximum of ~10GB.

Comment: Thanks! I have updated the answer because [AWS Lambda Now Supports Up to 10 GB Ephemeral Storage | AWS News Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/aws-lambda-now-supports-up-to-10-gb-ephemeral-storage/).